# Checking if only one specific component is selected in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a requirement to skip a page when only a particular component is selected in the component selection page. Please look at the below image

[image: Component Selection Page]

```
[Components]
Name: DBS\TRACE; Types: DBS TBLWOS; Description: DBS Tracing Bodylife Database;
```

The requirement is to skip a page when the option "DBS Tracing Bodylife Database" (highlighted in the image) alone is selected and clicked on Next button. If I select only that option, I am successfully able to skip the page using below code.

```pascal
if PageID = PageToBeSkipped.ID then begin
    Result := not (IsComponentSelected('not DBS\TRACE'));
end;
```

But If I select any other additional component along with the "DBS Tracing Bodylife Database" from this page which is nearly 20, the page should not be skipped. The above code skips the page if any additional component is selected too.

How can I handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test if any component, except one specific, is selected, you can use [`WizardSelectedComponents` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardselectedcomponents) (which returns a comma-separated list of selected components).

```pascal
function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;

  if PageID = PageToBeSkipped.ID then
  begin
    Result := (CompareText(WizardSelectedComponents(False), 'DBS,DBS\TRACE') = 0);
  end;
end;
```

Note that the `WizardSelectedComponents` returns even "partially" selected components groups.